# I can't display temperature on my website

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I'm new to Javascript and I followed a tutorial that is pretty easy to display open weather data on my website with javascript.
https://codepen.io/mattfroese/pen/WaeYQV
https://bytemaster.io/fetch-weather-openweathermap-api-javascript

It's very odd but it works on codepen and not my website...

Maybe you can help me ? Here is the code...

```js
const key = '';
if(key=='') document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = ('Remember to add your api key!');

function weatherBallon( cityID ) {
 fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=47.204530&lon=-1.563377&appid=OPENWEATHER_APP_ID')  
 .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) // Convert data to json
 .then(function(data) {
  drawWeather(data);
 })
 .catch(function() {
  // catch any errors
 });
}
function drawWeather( d ) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15);
 var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15)*1.8)+32);
  var description = d.weather[0].description; 
 
 document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;
 document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = celcius + '°';
 document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;
  
  if( description.indexOf('rain') > 0 ) {
   document.body.className = 'rainy';
  } else if( description.indexOf('cloud') > 0 ) {
   document.body.className = 'cloudy';
  } else if( description.indexOf('sunny') > 0 ) {
   document.body.className = 'sunny';
  } else {
   document.body.className = 'clear';
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
 weatherBallon( 6167865 );
}
```

```css
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0;
  height: 77px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font: 30px "Elastik-B";
  
}

.footer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom:15px;
    right:5%;
}

.footer li {
   text-align:right;
   float: right;
   display: block;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="footer">
<ul>
    <li><div id="temp">...</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: If you're planning on using this setup in production, I probably wouldn't post your real API key.

Comment: Open js console (press F12) and show us the errors

Comment: Not sure about structure of your HTML but I don't see any element with id description, after I commented out ```document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;``` in your code, temperature is shown just fine

Comment: It's working fine if you have description, temp and location as ID of one element each.

Comment: @ashu What do you mean ?

Comment: If you say it works in codepen but not on your website, are you sure you are in a document ready function?

Comment: @ArnaudAubry you need to add this to your html <div id="description"></div><div id="temp"></div><div id="location"></div>

Comment: yes but what if I don't want it to appear ? so it means these elements are interdependant in javascript

Comment: @ArnaudAubry if you don't want it to appear then remove these elements from your javascript file. When you try to grab element which doesn't exist, it cause issue and in the end your temperature will not appear.
Remove from your javascript:
```document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;```
AND
 ```document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;```

Comment: Ok ! that was the issue !! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have not added your api key in first line

```
const key = " ";
```

Please add api key and check if you are still getting an error message, try this

```
<script lang="text/javascript">
const key = 'b2b1b01a9261a8b31e450dffc404f9e9';
if(key=='') document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = ('Remember to add your api key!');

function weatherBallon( cityID ) {
    fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=47.204530&lon=-1.563377&appid=b2b1b01a9261a8b31e450dffc404f9e9')  
    .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() }) // Convert data to json
    .then(function(data) {
        drawWeather(data);
    })
    .catch(function() {
        // catch any errors
    });
}
function drawWeather( d ) {
  var celcius = Math.round(parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15);
    var fahrenheit = Math.round(((parseFloat(d.main.temp)-273.15)*1.8)+32);
  var description = d.weather[0].description; 

    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = description;
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = celcius + '°';
    document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = d.name;

  if( description.indexOf('rain') > 0 ) {
    document.body.className = 'rainy';
  } else if( description.indexOf('cloud') > 0 ) {
    document.body.className = 'cloudy';
  } else if( description.indexOf('sunny') > 0 ) {
    document.body.className = 'sunny';
  } else {
    document.body.className = 'clear';
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
    weatherBallon( 6167865 );
}
  </script>
```

Comment: They've added the key manually to the end of the URL. From the docs:  _"take your key and add it to the url as the appid parameter shown below."_

Comment: In that case you will have to modify the code, otherwise they key will be always empty and it will not execute the function

Comment: That just changes the contents of **#temp** if the key is not there. The rest should work fine (_for testing_) with the key at the end. There must be another issue here.

Comment: yes it doesn't work... It's already at the end of the url in the next step. I believe this part is just to remember me to add my own key.